# Django: Getting the page an object is on

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a class `Foo`. I want to know what page a particular instance of Foo will be on: eg: `api.myapp.com/foos/?page=25`.

Given an object:

`Foo.objects.get(id=500)`, how can I determine what page my instance will be on?

Comment: It'll depend on how many items are on a page, and how those instances are being sorted. Are the page sizes and sort order configurable? If not, could you share the code here to make it easier for people to answer?

Comment: If you can assume that (a) there are N items per page, (b) you're ordering by ID number, which starts at 0, and (c) there are no gaps in the ID numbers, then your instance with id=500 would be on floor(500/N). But if you can't assume (b) or (c), you'll probably have to do some more calculation to know where in the list it would be.

Comment: @bouteillebleu IDs are unfortunately UUIDs– but page sizes will be a constant 50 objects per page. Is the only way to find the page then to iterate through the whole queryset?

Comment: Assuming you're using the Paginator class (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/) then yes, it looks like you'd have to iterate through all the pages at least - it doesn't look from the docs like the objects themselves know what page they're on. So you'd probably have to iterate through them at least once to know what objects were on what page.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is a little bit different so you can do this,

```
model_ids = (list(Model.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)))
```

This will give you the list of the ids. After that,

```
get_page_number = model_ids.index(obj_id) // per_page_objects + 1
```

If the obj_id is 500 so the index will be 499

now if per_page_objects are 10 then it will give you page number by calculating (499 // 10 +1 = 50).
This means your object having an id 500 is on the 50th page.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

Django by itself does not predefine which url your model will be accessed through.
The documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) - "Django lets you design URLs however you want, with no framework limitations".
So the process is rather opposite:

- you define the url (look inside urls.py) and associate it with the view to be called for processing:

  ```
  from django.urls import path
  from . import views

  urlpatterns = [
      path('foos/', views.foo_list),
      path('foos/<int:id>/', views.foo_detail),
  ```
- you should define the views (usually in views.py)
- and inside the view you can call any models to fetch data from DB

You can implement your API with additional packages like Django Rest Framework.
It has [Routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) that allow you to define a set of urls at once. The following will generate URL patterns like '^foos/$' and '^foos/{pk}/$':

- you register your url within the router

  ```
  from rest_framework import routers

  router = routers.SimpleRouter()
  router.register(r'foos', FooViewSet)
  ```
- you should implement FooViewSet and make sure your model is used there.

Comment: This seems like a good response, but I'm not sure it's an answer to the question asked, which appears to be about pagination.

Comment: @bouteillebleu you could be right, I misread page reference as related to url design.